# Does Turning The GPIO Pins On/Off Without Any Circuits Connected Harm the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, pi-2

So, i'm just getting into raspberry pi and I am yet to have my order of circuit parts such as LEDs and resistors arrive.  My question is that if I turn the GPIO pins on without any circuits attached to the pins will my raspberry pi burn out, short out, or break in any way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

No, it will not. Unconnected pins will present simply high impedance, setting them as logical output and given value (high or low) definitely will not damage them or board when they are **not connected**.